# Crystal Report Load error with Local IIS

Tags: c#, iis, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to use Crystal Reports in my new web application.
I allready used it in an older project (VS 2008) and works great.

Now I want to use it in my new web application with Visual Studio 2015.
I installed Crystal report from http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 , version 'v.13.0.15.1840'
And in my project I installed the Crystal.Report.Essentials from the Nuget Manager.

My code looks like this:

```
ReportDocument rptEHBOFiche = new ReportDocument();
rptEHBOFiche.Load("C:\\TEMP\\InputFiche.rpt");
```

Everytime I get the error that the loading of the report had failed.
I tried other paths but nothing is working.

Does anyone has a solution?

EDIT:
**I found the problem, but not the solution.**
The problem is this doesn't work if my project is on Local ISS. If it's on ISS Express I have no problem..

I have set the app pool to enable 32 bit applications too.

Comment: Look at my second answer..

Comment: I installed the executable, and also the MSI 64 bit. Still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code?

```
if File.Exists ("C:\\TEMP\\InputFiche.rpt")
  rptEHBOFiche.Load("C:\\TEMP\\InputFiche.rpt"); 
else 
  throw new Exception ("wrong path");
```

EDIT 2 Answer

In http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 , "Install executable" is Crystal Reports Visual Studio integration. "MSI 64 bit" is IIS Runtime.
Install MSI 64 bit to have your IIS working. Don't lose your time on 32 bit apps, 64 bit work great.

Comment: It goes in the load functie, the file exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found the **solution**:
I needed to give my App Pool full rights to the c:\Windows\Temp folder